# How to show alert if my array contains the passed value using jQuery.inArray()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, input

I am storing the value of textbox in an array.Then, I'm storing the values in an array by splitting by comma separated values.

When I pass a value in `ExistsInArray` function I'm not getting the alert.

```
<input value="1,2,3,4" id="someid">
```

**JavaScript**

```
var txtboxVal=$("#someid").val();
var myarray=txtboxVal.split(",")

function ExistsInArray(id) {
  if (jQuery.inArray(id, myarray) !== -1) {
    alert('id');
  }
  ExistsInArray(3);
}
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/wucp20bu/)</kbd>

Comment: Not sure how `inArray` works but you are passing argument as Number but splitted values are string..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several issues:

- pass the `id` variable to the `alert()`, not a string, eg `alert(id)`
- move the `ExistsInArray()` call *outside* of itself - you're creating an infinite loop
- you're providing an int value to the function, yet the array contains strings.

Try this:

```
var txtboxVal = $("#someid").val();
var myarray = txtboxVal.split(",")

function ExistsInArray(id) {
    if ($.inArray(id, myarray) !== -1) {
        alert(id);
    }
}

ExistsInArray('3'); // note the quotes here
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/gdugdp9t/)

Comment: Or `txtboxVal.split(",").map(Number);`

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `ExistsInArray()` **inside itself**

Try to put it outside:

```
function ExistsInArray(id) {
  if (jQuery.inArray(id, myarray) !== -1) {
    alert('id');
  }
}
ExistsInArray(3);
```

Comment: `"3"` !== `3` `The comparison between values is strict` that's why. `jQuery.inArray(id.toString(), myarray)` would fix it   https://jsfiddle.net/wucp20bu/3/